# Laravel query builder left join from subquery

Tags: sql, laravel, query-builder

I'm using Laravel query builder and trying to do something like this:

```php
$builder = DB::table('mainTable')->where("mainTable.id", "=", 111);

$builder->leftJoinSub(
    DB::table('table2')
        ->where('table2.id', '=', DB::raw("mainTable.subtableId"))
        ->where('table2.region', '=', DB::raw("mainTable.region"))
        ->orderBy('table2.someOrder', 'DESC')
        ->select('kamery2.id')
        ->first(),
    'myId',
    'table2.id',
    '=',
    'myId'
);
```

And I'm getting

> The multi-part identifier "mainTable.subtableId" could not be bound.

However when I write it with `DB::raw('...')` it works.

```php
$builder->leftJoin(
    'table2',
    'table2.id',
    '=',
    DB::Raw("...")
);
```

So I'm trying to find out what I'm doing wrong. Did I make a syntactic mistake only? Or Laravel query's builder doesn't allow what I want to achieve and I have to use `->leftJoin(.... DB::raw() )` ?

Comment: Why are you trying to use that complex query instead of relations ? What are you really trying to do ?

Comment: You mean instead of Eloquent? Because the database is kinda legacy and it is not possible to use Eloquent on it. For example most of the database tables do not have a unique id. Uniqe identification for the row is combination of two or three columns.